# Two-dimensional arrays and user input

Tags: java, arrays, user-input

I'm curious if there is a way using the scanner class to get user input for initializing rows and colums in a array.

such as if you have a three by three array and you want the user to choose which row and colum to go to

something like :

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

int[][] arrayOfChoice = new int[][];

int user = arrayOfChoice[input.nextInt()][input.nextInt] = some value
```

I haven't tried this but I doubt it works but hope it gives an idea of what I'm looking to do and if there is a way to achive this I would be greatful to hear about it.

**EDIT**

let me try and clarify what I want to do

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ScannerTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int[][] arrayHu = new int[3][3];

        System.out.println("please enter the row and colum you would like to fill:");

        int[input.nextInt();][input.nextInt();] = 1;

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayhu));
    }
}
```

something like this where the user can enter which row and colum to put the value 1 in. how would I do that, thank you

Comment: Why haven't you tried this? Why do you doubt it works? What have you tried then?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this but only in a try catch statement.
The last line you wrote is also wrong

```
int user = arrayOfChoice[input.nextInt()][input.nextInt()] = some_value
```

some_value will be assigned to both the array and user

Answer (score 0):

It does work but there is a bit of an issue with your code. The below line

```
int[][] arrayOfChoice = new int[][];
```

won't work because you need to either initialize the array or give it dimensions.

```
int[][] arrayOfChoice = new int[3][3];
int[][] arrayOfChoice = new int[][]{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}};
```

Also for the last line:

```
int user = arrayOfChoice[input.nextInt()][input.nextInt] = some value
```

Both the variable user and the index at the two points input by user will equal to 'some value'. I am unsure if this is what you are trying to achieve or not.

Also I would caution that the user's input may be invalid (non-numeric, out of array bounds, etc.) which will crash the program. Maybe use a try catch block (Since this means user will only be defined inside the try catch block I moved it outside).

```
int user = 5;
try
{
    arrayOfChoice[input.nextInt()][input.nextInt()] = user;
}
catch(Exception e) 
{
    System.out.println("Invalid input!");
}
```

**Edits for the tic tac toe game:**

Everything I said still applies. There are many ways of doing this but here is an example.

1.Create a turn counter, scanner and board.

```
int turn = 0;
int[][] board = new int[3][3];
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

2.Create while loop which prints the board and asks user for input:

```
for(int[] i : board)
{
    for(int j : i)
    {
        System.out.print(j + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
System.out.println("Enter an x and y value:");
```

3.Get input from user:

```
board[input.nextInt()][input.nextInt()] = ((turn % 2) == 0 ? 2 : 1);
```

4.Create function to check board for win and break out of loop if found. Half can be written as below but diagonal must be checked as well.

```
/*Check row and column.*/
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    if((board[i][0] == board[i][1] && board[i][0] == board[i][2] && board[i][0] != 0) || 
        (board[0][i] == board[1][i] && board[0][i] == board[2][i] && board[0][i] != 0))
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

5.If winner is not found increase turn counter and start while loop. If winner is found print winner

```
System.out.println("Player " + ((turn % 2) == 0 ? 2 : 1) + " is the winner!");
```

6.Close scanner.

```
input.close();
```

Comment: ok I see what you are saying , let me give a little more detail as to what I'm trying to do. I'm making a tick-tac-toe game from the consul. so what I want to happen is that a user will pick an associated row and colum and then that's where the x or o will be marked in the rest of my code so for example ill have a system print that says pick a row and colum and that would be the associated array to hold that info [0][2] sort of thing would mark an x in the third box